# Is there a notion of transaction in GraphQL?

Tags: .net-core, graphql

To avoid looking after a ghost, I prefer to check if the notion of a transaction can exist in [GraphQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL) .

Let's say I have this:

```
mutation save_changes {
  change01 {
    
  }
  change02 {
    
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility for `change01` to be rolled back if `change02` fails?

Comment: Only commit the transaction when all operations succeed or roll it back if any of your operation fails.

Comment: Are you saying that it is supported by default?

Comment: I'm also looking to implement the same structure. Did you manage to implement this in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL is the API technology while transaction is a DB technology. As GraphQL is agnostic to the datasource(s) used to retrieve and persist data , so it is quite normal that GraphQL does not define anything related to the DB transaction and pretty sure it will never do that in the future. Otherwise , it will make GraphQL can only work with the datasource that support transaction which violates its datasource agnostic design principle. So it is up to the developers to define and implement how the transactional behaviour to be.

Comment: You are right. Since I use `strapi` for my GraphQL Server, I better direct my question to them. Hopefully, they managed to do that. I thought it could be some kind of standard for all graphql server implementations to respect.